# java lwjgl setting the mouses position without changing dx or dy

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl

Hello I am making a 3D game and now that I've started making something that lets the user interact with a mouse I have been a little stuck (well really stuck).
What I'm trying to do is when the user moves the mouse it gets moved back to the centre (or were the coordinates I entered are) without effecting the Mouse.getDX() and Mouse.getDY().
Here is my code for the part were I test for moving the mouse.

```
    public void onMouser(){
    yaw+=Mouse.getDX();
    pitch-=Mouse.getDY();

    Mouse.setCursorPosition(750, 500);
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void calculatePitchAndYaw() {
    pitch += Mouse.getY() - HEIGHT /2;
    yaw += Mouse.getX - WIDTH / 2;
    Mouse.setCursorPosition(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT /2);
}
```

Try something like this. So you wont turn back to your initial position.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change position of mouse with serCursorPosition without affect the Mouse.getDX();

You can try save vars before change cursos position:

```
int saveDX = Mouse.getDX();
int saveDY = Mouse.getDY();
Mouse.setCursorPosition(750, 500);
```

Regards.

Comment: @Maetschi that is what i have also tried to do but it wouldnt work.

Comment: Probably you cange values (saveDx and saveDy) on another instance of code or never calls this lines.